# Email subject line starts with “?utf-8?Q?” in codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

Email subject line starts with `?utf-8?Q?` in codeigniter 3.1

When I send email by email library email deliver properly but subject not showing properly it's look like `?utf-8?Q?====? sdfdfd ?utf-8?Q?`

Also I am using ion_auth for sending email.

If any suggestion please add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this code in you file

> \system\libraries   Email.php file

```
public function subject($subject)
{
  $subject = $this->_prep_q_encoding($subject);
  $this->set_header('Subject', $subject);
  return $this;
}
```

To

```
public function subject($subject)
{
   $subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
   $this->_set_header('Subject', $subject);
   return $this;
}
```

and set the email configuration in your email config

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'newline' => "\r\n",
    'crlf' => "\n",
    'mailtype' => "html"
);
```

Comment: your solution worked for me on Codeigniter 3.1.9 and saved me days and days of more swearing, thanks :)